Why is batch_size used as input_dim in Keras Embedding layer examples in this book?
I am reading the book Machine Learning Design Patterns by Valliappa Lakshmanan, Sara Robinson, Michael Munn
I've come across several code examples where batch_size is used as the input_dim parameter in the Keras Embedding layer, which seems confusing. Here’s an example:
batch_size = len(df)  # Using the entire dataset size for demo purposes
embedding_input = Input(shape=(sequence_length,))
embedding_layer = Embedding(batch_size, 64)(embedding_input)  # `batch_size` used here
embedding_layer = Flatten()(embedding_layer)
embedding_layer = Dense(32, activation='relu')(embedding_layer)

As I understand it, the Embedding layer should typically use the vocabulary size as input_dim and the embedding dimension as output_dim, so each unique token is mapped to an embedding. But using batch_size in place of input_dim doesn’t seem right.
Could someone clarify:
If there's any specific reason for using batch_size as input_dim in such examples?
What are the correct values for input_dim and output_dim in the Embedding layer?
Link to code cell before In:45 in
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-design-patterns/blob/master/02_data_representation/mixed_representation.ipynb
